# Adding a nav menu for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, navigation

I am trying to add a navigational menu which will go through a series of news articles. Here is my `WP_Query`

```
    $news = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'=>'news',
        'meta_key'  => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => '12',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    ));
```

The navigation menu for my blog posts looks like this:

```
<div class="col -align-left">
  <?php echo get_next_posts_link('&larr; Older Posts') ?>
</div>
<div class="col -align-right">
  <?php echo get_previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &rarr;') ?>
</div>
```

and this works for my blog posts. How can I achieve the same functionality for a custom post type?

When I use this for my custom post type it does navigate to the next page, however it displays the posts from the original page. It does not fetch the new for the next news articles.

Comment: Have you looked at [the codex page for `get_next_posts_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query)? Typically though, one would use the post type archive for a custom post type, which would eliminate this issue.

Comment: yes when I use this for my custom post type it does navigate to the next page, however it displays the posts from the original page.

Comment: That’s because you don’t specify a page number, so you always get the first page. Note how the example on that page gets and sets the `paged` argument in the query.